# Running an exe in C# with commandline parameters, suppressing the dos window

Tags: c#, lame

I am using lame for transcoding for one of my project. The issue is that when I call lame from C#, a DOS window pops out. Is there any way I can suppress this?

Here is my code so far:

```
Process converter =
    Process.Start(lameExePath, "-V2 \"" + waveFile + "\" \"" + mp3File + "\"");

converter.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: How about showing us some code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try something like:

```
using( var process = new Process() )
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "...";
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "...";
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.Start();
}
```

Comment: the  process.WaitForExit();  doesn't work quite right if this is used. Is it possible to avoid the Dos window as well as keep the program on hold, until the process terminates ?

Comment: @Egon: what is the problem with WaitForExit();? I am using it and I never had any problems so far.

Comment: I am using lame to change in file encode. in the next few lines I am playing the newly encoded file. If I do it without the dos window, I cribs saying the said file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are calling it via [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx), you can use the overload that takes [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo_members%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) that has its [`CreateNoWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) property set to `true` and its [`UseShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute(v=VS.90).aspx) set to `false`.

The `ProcessStartInfo` object can also be accessed via the `Process.StartInfo` property and can be set there directly before starting the process (easier if you have a small number of properties to setup).

Answer (score 3):

```
Process bhd = new Process(); 
bhd.StartInfo.FileName = "NSOMod.exe";
bhd.StartInfo.Arguments = "/mod NSOmod /d";
bhd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
bhd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

Is another way.

Answer (score 2):

This is my code that does a similar thing, (and also reads the output and return code)

```
        process.StartInfo.FileName = toolFilePath; 
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = parameters; 

        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; // needs to be false in order to redirect output 
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true; 
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true; // redirect all 3, as it should be all 3 or none 
        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(toolFilePath); 

        process.StartInfo.Domain = domain; 
        process.StartInfo.UserName = userName; 
        process.StartInfo.Password = decryptedPassword; 

        process.Start(); 

        output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); // read the output here... 

        process.WaitForExit(); // ...then wait for exit, as after exit, it can't read the output 

        returnCode = process.ExitCode; 

        process.Close(); // once we have read the exit code, can close the process
```